# Tour with IntroJs framework in primefaces tabView doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, intro.js

I'm using IntroJs framework (https://introjs.com/) and my problem is to do a tour (intro) on a tabView (primefaces component).
When I put the inline atribute `data-intro` in a `p:tab` component, the primefaces ignores them and the *html* component it generates cannot be seen by the introJs ***start()*** function.

**Here is my code:**

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" scrollable="true" styleClass="users">
    <p:tab title="ldap" id="tabLDAP" data-intro="test">
    <ui:include src="tabldap.xhtml" />
</p:tab>
```

Comment: Please read your question like if you were us... Do you think you could help out? I personally would not be able to. Please read [ask] and [mcve]...

Comment: sorry, frist time here. better?

Comment: Well, only a little better. There at least is some example code but it is not minimal, nor complete, nor is it verifieable

Answer (score 1):

To render attributes that are not JavaServer Faces attributes you need to use Pass-Through Attributes.
I see that you are using Primefaces, so this is one useful blog post:

> JSF 2.2 has a great feature to add dynamic attributes to a component
>   on runtime, these attributes are called pass through attributes.
>   PrimeFaces 4.0 is aimed to support JSF 2.0,  2.1 and 2.2 at the same
>   time using runtime detection and lately pass through attributes
>   support is added to 4.0;
>
> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
> xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
> xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
>
> <h:head>
> </h:head>
>
> <h:body>
>
> <p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" pt:placeholder="Watermark here"/>
>
> </h:body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> [Source: Primefaces Blog](https://www.primefaces.org/jsf-2-2-pass-through-attributes/)

Another useful article: [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial, Section 8.9.2 Using Pass-Through Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm)